# Add readme to apple's binary iphone

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I need to add some kind of readme to the binary I will send to apple.
But with XCode 4 the process is different and I cannot add any file to the .zip that is sent along with the binary.

How can I do that now? If there's not a way to do that, will I be able to send that Readme when the app is "in Review", when the reviewer asks me to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you submit an app in itunesconnect you can fill out the metadata (description , categorie ...) there is an field called "Review Notes (optional)". In this field you can write down your "README" for the Review process.

[image: itunesconnect screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, no other way of adding a PDF?

Comment: you could add a weblink to the pdf.